# Is ES6 imported code strict?

Tags: javascript, import, module, strict

Say that I have a library that relies on non-strict semantics, like coercing a top-level `this` to the global object:

```
this.library = { foo: function () {} };
```

Say that I try to import this library using `import`:

```
import './library';
library.foo();
```

Since I used `import`, does that mean the library code implicitly runs in strict mode (and breaks, since `this` is `undefined` in strict code)? The ECMAScript spec [says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-strict-mode-code),

> Module code is always strict mode code.

and for the [definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-types-of-source-code) of "module code,"

> Module code is source text that is code that is provided as a `ModuleBody`.

And a `ModuleBody` [consists of](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-modules) a `ModuleItemList`, which consists of `ModuleItem`'s, which could include `ImportDeclaration`, `ExportDeclaration` and `StatementListItem`, and a `StatementListItem` [could be](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-block) a `Statement` or `Declaration`. Which implies that any code could be "module code" depending on the context it is loaded, even without the prescence of an `import` or `export` declaration.

Also, the definition of `[[RequestedModules]]` field from [15.2.1.16](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-source-text-module-records) implies that the `ModuleSpecifier` used in `ImportDeclaration` indeed specifies the name of a "module:"

> A List of all the `ModuleSpecifier` strings used by the module represented by this record to request the importation of a module.

It would appear that the module system is backwards-incompatible with non-strict code. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this conversation](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3807):

> A module is not a JavaScript program that includes import/export
>   statements. Just because they MAY contain import/export statements
>   does not mean that they MUST have them. You cannot always look at a
>   program and determine whether or not it is a module. . . .
>
> Since [*ModuleBody* is optional](http://ModuleBody%20is%20optional), the empty program is a Module.
>   The empty program does not contain an export statement.

So, yes, the module system is backwards-incompatible with non-strict code. I suppose code not using the module system is not really fit for participation in the system, because it's likely exporting global variables, which defeats the purpose of it.

Therefore, in order to interoperate, old code will have to be updated either to provide an `export` declaration or to use strict mode (and/or "guaranteed" non-strict techniques like `Function('return this')()`, instead of a *supposedly* non-strict top-level `this`).